# Копирование файлов на Google Drive с помощью Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive

Есть скрипт, который делает резервную копию из одно папки в другую на Google Drive.

```
function copyFile_(fileId, folderId) {
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd - HH:mm:ss');
  file.makeCopy(`${file.getName()}.BACKUP - ${date}`, folder);
}
```

Если запустить на файл *.gsheet, то копирование происходит в папку по указанному ID.
Если запустить на файл *.gscript, то копирование происходит в корень Google Drive.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, это какой-то баг, который возникает при создании новых файлов Apps Script. Попробуйте вот так

```js
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd - HH:mm:ss');
  const copy = file.makeCopy(`${file.getName()}.BACKUP - ${date}`, folder);
  if (copy.getMimeType() === 'application/vnd.google-apps.script')
    copy.moveTo(folder);
```